# Stackoverflow Release Notes

Tags: support

While using SO I see that new features are implemented and I was wondering if there are release notes that can be viewed by public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding the following post to your favorites.  It is maintained by the community with team input.

[Recent Feature Changes To Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)